# how to reload a div after ajax call in which is a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, reload

I am reloading a div after ajax like below:

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    .....
    success: function(data) {       
        $('.result').html(data);        
        $(".comments-body").load(" .comments-body > *"); // reload div comments-body from comments
   },
```

In the div `.comments-body` there is a form.

The form:

```
<form class="comment_form" action="" method="POST" role="form"> 
    .....
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit_nested_comment">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Re-submitting this form is not possible anymore after the div is dynimically reloaded. Only after a hard refresh.
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) this way: `$('body').on('submit', '.comment_form', function (e) {....})`

Comment: unfortunatley, this way the form doesn't work even the first time...

Comment: I can tell you that is impossible.

Comment: I agree. It works great now! Stupid mistake i made. thnx for the anser.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the div by its id rather then the class like this :

```
   $("#divid").load(" #divid");
```